# Visibility as per Backward Ownership of Records of Custom Object

Tags: sharing-rule

In custom object, I need to create a sharing rule such that it will be visible to owner1 if he creates a record and then if the records gets assigned to some other queue, then it will be visible to both owner1 and assigned person.

Please suggest.

Comment: Others may have a better approach, but at a guess you'll need to add an `OriginalOwnerId` field that is populated when the record is inserted with the OwnerId and include that field in your sharing rules.

Comment: Hi Keith.I am writing a trigger on that custom sharing object and granting access to the Assigned_To field by UserOrGroupId of sharing obj.
But Assigned_To has a lookup to contacts not User. Any idea how to grant access to contact lookup in a sharing reason trigger ?

Comment: I don't; best to add this detailed information to your question if its what you really want to know.